# Excel VBA Count Times a date occurs within 2 weeks of a previous date

Tags: vba, excel, foreach, excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet containing Record Number, Account, Start, and Finish Date.
I am attempting to get a count of the number of times a retest was done within 14 days of the end date. I have been able to write the code to get the distinct occurrences of the dates but I am having trouble with the counts.

[[image: Original filtered dataset[1]]

```
Sub DistinctObs()


    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim nws As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long, i As Long, j As Long
    Dim col As New Collection
    Dim Itm
    Dim cField As String

    Const deLim As String = "#"


    ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)).Name = "DistinctObs"

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    Set nws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DistinctObs")

    With ws
        lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 2 To lRow
            cField = .Range("A" & i).Value & deLim & _
                     .Range("B" & i).Value & deLim & _
                     .Range("G" & i).Value & deLim & _
                     .Range("I" & i).Value

            On Error Resume Next
            col.Add cField, CStr(cField)
            On Error GoTo 0
        Next i

        i = 2

        .Range("A1:B1").Copy nws.Range("A1")
        .Range("G1").Copy nws.Range("C1")
        .Range("I1").Copy nws.Range("D1")
         nws.Range("E1").Value = "Count"


        For Each Itm In col
            nws.Range("A" & i).Value = Split(Itm, deLim)(0)
            nws.Range("B" & i).Value = Split(Itm, deLim)(1)
            nws.Range("C" & i).Value = Split(Itm, deLim)(2)
            nws.Range("D" & i).Value = Split(Itm, deLim)(3)




            For j = 2 To lRow
                cField = .Range("A" & j).Value & deLim & _
                         .Range("B" & j).Value & deLim & _
                         .Range("G" & j).Value & deLim & _
                         .Range("I" & j).Value

                If Itm = cField Then nCount = nCount + 1
            Next
            nws.Range("E1" & i).Value = nCount

            i = i + 1
            nCount = 0
        Next Itm
    End With
End Sub
```

This code results in this filtered data list
[image: Filtered Result]

This is the desired result that I am having trouble implementing in code. 
[image: Desired Result]

Comment: I don't see how you're getting a ReTest of 3 from the data you're providing? Also what makes 8/9/2018 the start date that you want to check from? Are you checking how many ReTests there have been within 14 days of each new start date?

Comment: My apologies.. It started off as something I thought was simple but that quickly changed and I may be a bit over my head.

The lowest finish date is the first occurrence. Each start date within 14 days of that date would increase the count by 1. Then the next Finish Date to occur 14 or more days later would restart that cycle. In the example above 09/22 would be the next date to start the 14 day cycle.

Comment: To further clarify Member 2425788 tested initially on 08/09 and finished on the 10th. He tested 3 more times (8/14, 8/17, and 8/21) within the next 14 days. 

If he had come in and tested again between 9/22 and 10/6 I would count them towards the 09/22 start date.

Comment: And record number and account number have to match?

Comment: Record number is most important. A new account number is issued with different aspects of the test. A record number can have multiple account numbers per day but all that matters is whether that person (record number) has tested again within 14 days X period. Starting at the lowest available finish date.

Comment: Okay so we *don't* care about the account number at all then?

Comment: We don't care about the account number.

Comment: Yes my bad, I mis-typed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay bear with me, this was a little tricky. Here is the code I used. I had the sample data in `Sheet1` and the destination table was in `Sheet2.

It's important to have your data sorted by Record Number, Smallest to Largest, then Finish Date, Oldest to Newest.

```
Option Explicit
Sub Test()

Dim i As Long, j As Long, recordnumber As Long
Dim sht1 As Worksheet, sht2 As Worksheet
Dim lastdate As Date

Set sht1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set sht2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

j = 2

For i = 2 To sht1.Cells(sht1.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    If i = 2 Then
       sht2.Range(sht2.Cells(j, 1), sht2.Cells(j, 4)).Value = _
       sht1.Range(sht1.Cells(i, 1), sht1.Cells(i, 4)).Value
       recordnumber = sht2.Cells(j, 1).Value
       lastdate = sht2.Cells(j, 4).Value
    End If

    If i > 2 Then

        'make a new line for new record
        If sht1.Cells(i, 1).Value > recordnumber Then

            j = j + 1
            sht2.Range(sht2.Cells(j, 1), sht2.Cells(j, 4)).Value = _
            sht1.Range(sht1.Cells(i, 1), sht1.Cells(i, 4)).Value
            recordnumber = sht2.Cells(j, 1).Value
            lastdate = sht2.Cells(j, 4).Value

        'increase retest count
        ElseIf sht1.Cells(i, 1).Value = sht2.Cells(j, 1).Value And _
               sht1.Cells(i, 4).Value - sht2.Cells(j, 4).Value > 0 And _
               sht1.Cells(i, 4).Value - sht2.Cells(j, 4).Value < 14 And _
               sht1.Cells(i, 4).Value <> lastdate Then

            sht2.Cells(j, 5).Value = sht2.Cells(j, 5).Value + 1
            lastdate = sht1.Cells(i, 4).Value

        'make new line for same record, new date 14 days out
        ElseIf sht1.Cells(i, 1).Value = sht2.Cells(j, 1).Value And _
               sht1.Cells(i, 4).Value - sht2.Cells(j, 4).Value > 14 Then

            j = j + 1
            sht2.Range(sht2.Cells(j, 1), sht2.Cells(j, 4)).Value = _
            sht1.Range(sht1.Cells(i, 1), sht1.Cells(i, 4)).Value
            recordnumber = sht2.Cells(j, 1).Value
            lastdate = sht2.Cells(j, 4).Value

        End If
    End If

Next i

End Sub
```

Sample data:

[image: img1]

After result on `Sheet2`:

[image: img2]